# How can all ports be closed?

Tags: ip, network-scanners, ports

I was faced that, there was an hacker attacking my gmail account.

With the help of google service, I got the information about that hacker. Again next day he was attacking my pc.

When I scanned the IP for an open port, It goes down and no single port was found open.

How is it possible? How can I close my all ports to protect my system?

Comment: This is like asking: 'my car doesn't work, how can i fix it?'.

Comment: if i really don't know how to close open ports , then what is wrong in it?. M just new here

Comment: You should provide more information in your question, and forget about closing all ports, there no such thing, but consider using firewall.

Comment: You scanned an IP which was attacking you, and all ports on that IP were closed? It's not clear from your question...

Comment: @Matthew yes, exactly I was using nmap for port scanning. Also used ping.eu but as generally these tools shows some open port of some general IPs, unlike that there was no open port was showing.

Comment: A firewall on the attackers side may have detected and blocked your scan.

Comment: You need to add more details to this question if you want it to be re-opened. Like, what were you scanning? Why do you want to close ports (what do you think that will do for you)? Why do you want to close ports on your local system, when it was a Google account that was being attacked?

Answer (score 3):

Ports are like holes in a wall, they exist but if no one is paying attention to them its no use to throw things at them.

A program uses ports (or sockets) to connect with other devices in the same network (and through routing techniques the program may reach other networks). The way this works is that the program opens a connection to the outside and listens to that connection that it opened. The program has to do something special to listen to connections incoming from the outside (like HTTP servers do, they take every connection that goes to port 80 -for example- and process that request).

If the program does not do this *something special* thing, then even if a connection goes through that port, the program will not process it and it goes to void.

When you got the IP of your attacker you scanned for open ports, but the attacker did not have a program listening for connections from the outside world (or had it set in a way that it would only log your connection requests but do nothing with them).

The best way to protect yourself from attacks like this is by installing a firewall and maybe a network monitor, for example Little Snitch will tell you every time a program a connection happens to or from your computer, and you can block or allow that connection. You will see that at least in OSX there are many calls to Apple servers.

Comment: That doesn't matter, the example with Little Snitch and OSX->Apple was just an example